# How to style and Array object in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

how would I be able to take each array and style them differently in CSS NOT in JS ?

```js
count = ['1','2','3','4'];
container = document.getElementById('itemsContainer');
  for(i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
    container.innerHTML+='<div class="items"></div>';
  }

var square= document.getElementsByClassName('items')[2];
square.style.backgroundColor='red';
```

```css
.items{
  margin-top:10px;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:gold;
```

```html
<div id="itemsContainer"></div>
```

Comment: what are the different CSS classes you want to apply ?

Comment: use nth-child.....

Answer (score 5):

Using the [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class selector, we can differentiate between the elements without having any unique identifiers on the elements themselves. We don't even need an array.

```js
container = document.getElementById('itemsContainer');

for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    container.innerHTML+='<div class="items"></div>';
}
```

```css
.items{
  margin-top:10px;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:gray;
 }

.items:nth-child(1){ background:gold; }
.items:nth-child(2){ background:green; }
.items:nth-child(3){ background:red; }
.items:nth-child(4){ background:blue; }
```

```html
<div id="itemsContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your JS to create a unique class for each item, then in your CSS, reference those classes

```js
count = ['1','2','3','4'];
container = document.getElementById('itemsContainer');
  for(i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
    container.innerHTML+='<div class="items item' + i + '"></div>';
  }
```

```css
.items{
  margin-top:10px;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:gold;}

.item1 {
  background: green;
}
.item2 {
  background: blue;  
}
```

```html
<div id="itemsContainer"></div>
```

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко that's one solution, this is another.

Comment: Thanks both answers are get !! IS their away that I could add you guy to a friends list ? Im really new to JS / coding need some Friends lol

Comment: This site doesn't do "friends". It's the quality of the individual answers that counts, not the persons who post them. That's only natural: if you like one answer by someone, that doesn't necessarily mean you'll like all answers by that person. So the identify of the poster is unimportant. With the exception of Jon Skeet of course.